# How to select document Ids that are being populated via Flask on page load

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am using a submit button to pass form values into flask, which then populate the ids and values of an html table on another page.

I then want to select those values by their ids and use them to filter a dataset. However, I'm finding that when I try to use `d3.select(#thing-id).value`, I am getting back `undefined`, I think because the file which is selecting the ids is running before they are populated in the html.

I've tried to use a variety of selection methods including d3 and get Document by Id.

The Flask:

```
@app.route("/prediction", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def predict():
   if request.method == 'POST':

            new_film = [request.form["adults"], request.form["years"], 
  request.form["film_length"], \
            request.form["genre_1"], request.form["genre_2"], request.form["genre_3"]]


        def commentary(rating):
            if rating <= 3:
                comment = "This sucks worse than what Rachel said"
            elif rating <= 6:
                comment = "Mediocre at best"
            else:
                comment = "The best thing since sliced bread"

            return comment


        prediction = {
            "adults_entered1": new_film[0],
            "years_entered1": new_film[1],
            "film_length_entered1": new_film[2],
            "genre1_entered1" : new_film[3], 
            "genre2_entered1" : new_film[4],
            "genre3_entered1" : new_film[5],
            "prediction": commentary(rating[0]),
            "rating": rating[0]
        }

        for key, value in prediction.items():
           print(f"{key}: {value}")

    return render_template('prediction.html', result=prediction)
```

The html:

```
<tbody id="filter-table"></tbody>
    <tr>
        {% if result %}
            {% for key, value in result.items() %}
                <td id={{key}}>
                    {{value}}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
```

The Javascript:

```
filter_val = d3.select(#adults_entered1).value
console.log(filter_val)
```

I would expect to be returned the `{{value}}` for the `adults_entered1`. Instead it is `undefined`.

Comment: Why is the table row (`tr`) outside the table body (`tbody`)?